BCP Inputting Incorrect Integer Data
I am running a bcp command to load some test data from local linux to a remote mssql db. The data is semi-randomly generated ints for testing purposes.
bcp test_load in /tmp/small_insert_test.csv -S <Server> -U <UID> -P <PWD> -d <DB> -f bcp.fmt -u
bcp.fmt looks like:
14.0
3
1       SQLINT              0       4       ","    1     site_id                                      ""
2       SQLINT              0       4       ","    2     view_id                                    ""
3       SQLINT              0       4       "\n"   3     content_id                                   ""

The target table test_load is a simple table with fields site_id, view_id and content_id, all INTs.
The weird thing is while the bcp is working, the data being inserted does not resemble the source data.
Here is the source data, all of it:
6,47603,4519004
6,47603,4521834
6,47603,4521904
6,47603,4521924
6,47603,4521934
6,47603,4522024
6,47603,4522094
6,47603,4522134
6,47603,4522544
6,47603,4522624

But here is the inserted data when I query select * from test_load (ignore the quotes etc thats just due to how I copied it to clipboard)
"54"    "808859444" "959526196"
"54"    "808859444" "825374004"
"54"    "808859444" "825374004"
"54"    "808859444" "825374004"
"54"    "808859444" "825374004"
"54"    "808859444" "842151220"
"54"    "808859444" "842151220"
"54"    "808859444" "842151220"
"54"    "808859444" "842151220"
"54"    "808859444" "842151220"

This is the input I get from running the bcp
Starting copy...

10 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 124    Average : (80.6 rows per sec.)

I cannot understand what bcp is doing here. I've truncated and reran bcp a few times and these values are consistent. It looks like its somehow translating the original ints into different values, but I don't understand why.

How many rows are you inserting in total? Are you saying that your input small_insert_test.csv file does not contain any rows with 54 in the first column and that they should all be 6 instead? Doing SELECT * FROM test_load is not going to return rows in the same order they were inserted - what happens if you specify WHERE and ORDER BY? Is this just old data (e.g. did you TRUNCATE the table before each import?).

Its 10 rows, I provided the full contents of the file and the full contents of the table after the load in my question. I've truncated the table between loads. All the site_ids should be 6.

I can replicate the behaviour with their example, @Dai

You are not importing the file you think you are. Check your filenames and paths.

wrong I was importing the correct file

For demonstration purposes, again, I can replicate the behaviour the OP states ( @BartMcEndree ): Image

If you are creating a non-XML format file for a delimited text file, you can specify 0 for the host file data length of every data field.

How does it behave if you import all columns as SQLCHAR?

Switching from SQLINT to SQLCHAR in the bcp.fmt file ended up resolving it

To use SQLINT in the format file the data would have to be in binary e.g. 0x06 instead of 0x36 (ASCII 54 ) '6'

I was able to identify a solution. The issue is that the bcp.fmt file was using SQLINT instead of SQLCHAR. Even though the values were integer, when bcp sees SQLINT apparently assumes the data is binary so it was expanding the integers.
As documented:

*Data files that are stored in character format use char as the file storage type. Therefore, for character data files, SQLCHAR is the only data type that appears in a format file.

I also switched the row terminator from '\n' to '\r\n'.
